# Zimbra mail goes to spam

Tags: spf, zimbra

I am using to send email, but facing little issue my mails are going to spam instead of inbox, I don't know why it is happening so, I have checked the header of the spam mail and find some things which may be creating problem

> Received-SPF: none (domain of abc.com does not designate permitted sender hosts)
>
> dkim=neutral (no sig)
>
> Message-ID: <1730254841.66.1491377016006.JavaMail.zimbra@abc.com>

I have used mxtool and fond missing reverse dns as well. Whether these are the reasons I am getting my mail in spam or not and How can i solve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be fixed with an TXT Record in your domain registrar. At least that's what I did.

I added the following TXT Record for my domain:

Type: `TXT`
Host: `mydomain.com`
Value:`v=spf1 ip4:YOUR.SERVER.IP.HERE ~all`
TTL: `Automatic`

[image: DNS Record]

It could take the DNS a while to update the record. But after that, your mails shouldn't land in the spam folder anymore.

Comment: But where i have to add that, Because its my own mail server

Comment: @Kashif In your domain registrar where you bought the domain